# How to broadcast screen recording using HLS in iOS/Swift

Tags: ios, swift, http-live-streaming, broadcast, screen-recording

I want to broadcast my screen recording using HLS. I have found broadcast screen recording using RTMP, but as server for rtmp costs more, my client wants to go for HLS.

Comment: I guess you can use [ReplayKit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/replaykit) from Apple

Answer (score 0):

HLS is a terrible contribution format. The majority of services use RTMP for contribution, and repackage server side to HLS for a CDN delivery.

Comment: Yes, I got to know about this but here client is demanding for HLS if you have demo or example code using HLS in swift provide here.

Comment: The client is almost certainly wrong, and will likely not be happy with the results. You should try to educate them.

Comment: Can you have some demo implemented using HLS in swift.?